# Grant user DDL permissions on specific schema

Tags: sql-server, permissions, schema

Using SQL Server (2008), is it possible to grant a specific user full control of the objects under a specific schema? This includes create/drop/alert table. Its important that this user isn't not given `db_ddladmin` role because that would give him access to other tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a role in the database, assign all appropriate permissions(SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, EXECUTE, etc.) to the role, and then assign the user to that role.

Comment: This question is about DDL, but your answer discusses DML permissions.